# How to make lowntfs-3g case preserving?

Tags: ntfs, ntfs-3g

I want to use NTFS on a shared partition between Windows and Linux (dual boot). However, if I mount it using ntfs-3g, it will become case sensitive. If I mount it using lowntfs-3g with windows_names and ignore_case, all filenames become lowercase. How do I mount an NTFS partition on linux in case insensitive yet case preserving mode, like on Windows?

Using Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: What do you mean by 'preserving mode'?  Do you mean preserve the 'ignore_case' and `windows_names` arguments?  Because those can be 'persisted' with specialized `/etc/fstab` configurations for that drive

Comment: Like I want it to be case insensitive (HeLlo and hello refer to the same file) but let's say I save a file as HeLlo it remains as HeLlo instead of being displayed as HeLlo. Basically, like how Windows handles NTFS and also like how Linux handles vfat.